# How to change all items on Column dependin on which one has been tapped

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure if how to do this.

I have a Column of AnimatedContainers. Initially all of them are 200 height. I want to implement some kind of callback, so when user tap on one item, this one becomes smaller(say 100 height) and the rest of the item in the list disappear. My AnimatedContainers are Stateful widgets

I guess I would have to use to callbacks, one for the columnn (parent) and the other to notify the children, but I don't know how to do this.

Summarised, what I have right now is

`Stateless(Column(Stateful(List<AnimatedContainer>)))`

If something is not clear please comment

Thanks

EDIT to add some code and more info

```
class SectionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  double screenHeight;
  Stream stream;
  int index;

  SectionButton(this.screenHeight, this.stream, this.index);

  @override
  _SectionButtonState createState() => _SectionButtonState();
}

class _SectionButtonState extends State<SectionButton> {
  double height;
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  initState() {
    super.initState();

    this.height = this.widget.screenHeight / n_buttons;

    streamSubscription =
        widget.stream.listen((_) => collapse(this.widget.index));
  }

  void collapse(int i) {
    if (this.widget.index != i) {
      setState(() {
        this.height = 0;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        this.height = this.widget.screenHeight / appBarFraction;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamSubscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      height: this.height,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> sections = [];
  bool areCollapsed = false;
  final changeNotifier = new StreamController.broadcast();

  void createSections(screenHeight) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonNames.length; i++) {
      this.sections.add(GestureDetector(onTap:(){
        print("Section i was tapped");
        changeNotifier.sink.add(i);}, //THIS IS NOT WORKING
      child: SectionButton(screenHeight, changeNotifier.stream, i),),);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double screenHeight =
        mediaQueryData.size.height - mediaQueryData.padding.vertical;

    createSections(screenHeight);

    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Column(children: this.sections)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

BTW what I'm trying to implement is something like this:

[image: ui menu]

Comment: If you already have the current code, you could put it here so other can easily continue from there.

Comment: @TruongSinh Done. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your height in a variable and wrap your widget with [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() { _height = 100.0; });
  },
  child: Container(
    child: Text('Click Me'),
  ),
)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [AnimatedSize](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html) Widget.

> Animated widget that automatically transitions its size over a given
>   duration whenever the given child's size changes.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. What I don't know, is how to make callbacks or listeners from other widgets (fathers and children)

Comment: how are you managing your state? using any state manger such as scoped_model will help. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that